# How do I get faster redundancy reduction without nested for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have a chunk of code that I would like to try to speed up. I have been using tensorflow a little if that would be a good way to solve this problem. This is code that is a part of a large simulation I am working on. This code, however, takes way too long to run. I have a way of changing how frequently on surfaces they are divided up and as of right now with a 10x worse resolution, this loop runs for upwards of an hour. Does anyone have any tips to speed this up?

```
Points = PlanesList[0:3,0:3]
Indices = np.array([[0],[1],[2]])
print(np.prod(PlanesList[0,:].shape))
for k in range(1,int(np.prod(PlanesList[0,:].shape)/3)+1):
    for ind in range(1,int(np.prod(Points.shape)/3)+1):
        truths = np.array([False,False,False])
        if np.all(PlanesList[0:3,(3*k-3)] == Points[0:3,ind-1]):
            index1=ind-1
            truths[0] = True
        if np.all(PlanesList[0:3,(3*k-2)] == Points[0:3,ind-1]):
            index2=ind-1
            truths[1] = True
        if np.all(PlanesList[0:3,(3*k-1)] == Points[0:3,ind-1]):
            index3=ind-1
            truths[2] = True
    if truths[0] == False:
        Points = np.column_stack([Points,PlanesList[0:3,(3*k-3)]])
        index1 = np.prod(Points[0,:].shape)-1
    if truths[1] == False:
        Points = np.column_stack([Points,PlanesList[0:3,(3*k-2)]])
        index2 = np.prod(Points[0,:].shape)-1
    if truths[2] == False:
        Points = np.column_stack([Points,PlanesList[0:3,(3*k-1)]])
        index3 = np.prod(Points[0,:].shape)-1
    Tempind = np.array([[int(index1)],[int(index2)],[int(index3)]])
    Indices = np.column_stack([Indices,Tempind])
```

The purpose of this code is to remove redundancies from the array PlanesList. Due to the way I have the array created, I have yet to come up with a way to form it without redundancies. PlanesList is an array containing sets of 3D triangles and for later on in the simulation, I need to be able to locate these triangles. Row 0 are X coordinates, Row 1 is Y, and Row 2 is Z. PlanesList is a 2D array with upwards of 60,000 columns (20,000 triangles) and exactly 3 rows.

Comment: when you say remove redundancies do you mean if 1,2,3 is one point to remove all other instances of 1,2,3 (3,2,1 or 213 or 231)?

Comment: if the point is (1,2,3), I want to remove all other instances of (1,2,3) because there is guaranteed to be 8 other times it occurs I think. either way, any point that is in PlanesList is guaranteed to have another instance of the same exact point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce identical columns in a numpy array to a single occurrence, you can use [np.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the `axis` argument.

**Example data:**

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,10)) 
a[:,3] = a[:,0]  # Duplicate one column
```

**Reduction:**

```
a_reduced = np.unique(a, axis=1)
```

Note that this will sort your array.

Also, note that the `axis` argument was added in numpy version `1.13.0`. I assume that the underlying implementation is fast, though faster solutions specifically tailored to your problem may exist.

---

*Edit:* If you want to know the index that the reduced points had in the full array, use the `return_index` argument:

```
a_reduced, a_indices = np.unique(a, axis=1, return_index=True)
```